# Split data of two worksheets into two worksheets in other Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with two worksheets, each with a table. The tables have column A (Region) in common.

Every Monday I split this file, which has a few thousand lines, by Region.
I end up with about 30 files, each with two sheets.

I want to automate this. I came up with a macro that splits the data by the values in column A (Region) in the first sheet:

```vb
Sub Split_Files()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 1
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "XYZ"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & "Access Rights Review " & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

How can I incorporate the second worksheet table to be also split and added to the file of each region?

Comment: If you say "I was able to come up with a macro" but then post code copied from https://dailydevsblog.com/troubleshoot/resolved-q-how-can-i-split-data-into-multiple-workbooks-files-based-on-column-in-excel-138282/  without stating that, all we can do is wonder why you're not able to fix your own code.  It's helpful for us to have some idea of your level of VBA knowledge.

Comment: OK, I'm a beginner at VBA. Yes, I found that code online and functioned better than a prior one I developed myself, so I sticked with it

Comment: Are the values in ColA of each of the two sheets distinct per sheet, or do the same values occur across both sheets (mostly or partly) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - similar to your existing code but uses a Collection to hold the source worksheets.

*EDIT* - added searching for a column header instead of using a fixed column position.

```vb
Sub Split_Files()
    Const dFileExtension As String = ".xlsx"  'include "."
    Const dFolderPath As String = "C:\Temp\"  'include ending "\"
    
    Dim dict As Object, wsNum As Long, dws As Worksheet, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range
    Dim colWs As New Collection, ws As Worksheet, splitCol As Variant, fileExt, splitColNum As Variant
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dfcell As Range, dFilePath As String, folderpath, key
    
    'add the sheets to be split up
    colWs.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    colWs.Add ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    splitCol = Application.InputBox("Which column would you like to filter by?", _
                                    "Filter Column", 1, , , , , 1 + 2) 'number/string
    If Len(Trim(splitCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    
    'collect unique values from the sheets to be split
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    For Each sws In colWs
        If sws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
        Set dict = UniqueColumnValues(sws.Cells(2, splitCol), dict)
    Next sws
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        wsNum = 0 'reset destination sheet index
        For Each sws In colWs
            
            splitColNum = Application.Match(splitCol, sws.Rows(1), 0) 'find the column position
            If Not IsError(splitColNum) Then 'got a match?
            
                wsNum = wsNum + 1
                If wsNum > dwb.Worksheets.Count Then dwb.Worksheets.Add after:=dws
                Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(wsNum)
                dws.Name = sws.Name
                
                Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
                srg.Rows(1).Copy
                dws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
                If srg.Rows.Count > 3 Then
                    srg.AutoFilter splitCol, key
                    srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dws.Range("A1")
                    sws.ShowAllData
                End If
            Else
                'alert if column header is missing?
            End If 'found the split column
        Next sws
        
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & "Access Rights Review " & key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next key
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
End Sub

'Collect unique values in column, starting at `startCell` until last occupied cell
'   in that column.  Optionally append those values into a supplied dictionary object.
Function UniqueColumnValues(startCell As Range, Optional dict As Object = Nothing)
    Dim c As Range, arr, r As Long, v
    If dict Is Nothing Then Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With startCell.Worksheet
        'read all values to an array (faster than cell-by-cell looping)
        arr = .Range(startCell, .Cells(Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        v = arr(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                dict(v) = True
            End If 'not blank
        End If     'not an error
    Next r
    Set UniqueColumnValues = dict
End Function
```

Comment: One more thing please, the above code will filter the data based on the column number selected on the Input box, but if instead of selecting a column number, I want to select a column by its header name, also coming from the input box? This header name is common again to all the sheets, however they will be in different positions, depending on the sheet. Many thanks

Comment: See update above.